# Encode url by Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, url, encode, encodeuricomponent

Friends, I am currently using the below `function` to `encode` my data and send them through `GET` method... I am using `ajax` to send and `php` to receive them...

```
function urlencode(a){
     a=encodeURIComponent(a);
     a=a.replace(/\\/g,'%5C');
     a=a.replace(/!/g,'%21');
     a=a.replace(/'/g,'%27');
     a=a.replace(/\(/g,'%28');
     a=a.replace(/\)/g,'%29');
     a=a.replace(/\*/g,'%2A');
     a=a.replace(/~/g,'%7E');
     a=a.replace(/%20/g,'+');
     a=a.replace(/%26amp%3B/gi,'%26');
     a=a.replace(/%26lt%3B/gi,'%3C');
     a=a.replace(/%26gt%3B/gi,'%3E');
     a=a.replace(/%26nbsp%3B/gi,'%C2%A0');
     return a;
}
```

after passing the string through `encodeURIComponent()`, I used extra `replace()` method so that the function encode the string for my link as ***similar*** as `php`...

Now my question is do anyone know any shorter or easy alternative way to do the same thing...

I place this question only for ***learning purpose***... ***no jQuery please...***

Comment: I don't understand why a down vote for this question...??

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but the point of what you are doing seems really questionable. (Edit: ahh, I see now)

Comment: @Pekka I didn't point at you... to him who did that... costed his free first down vote in my question...

Comment: Always, always use built-in methods to escape things. Never roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`escape()` instead of `encodeURIComponent`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) will eliminate at least some of the replace()'s you're using.  E.g:

```
function urlencode(a){
 return escape(a);
   .replace(/\*/g,'%2A');
   .replace(/%20/g,'+');
   .replace(/%26amp%3B/gi,'%26');
   .replace(/%26lt%3B/gi,'%3C');
   .replace(/%26gt%3B/gi,'%3E');
   .replace(/%26nbsp%3B/gi,'%C2%A0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending GET requests from JS to PHP, you should use

- [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), for each parameter, on the javascript side
- **nothing** on the PHP side (because [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is already `urldecode()`d; read the notes section in its linked documentation)

If you have to url-encode things in PHP, use `urlencode()`, which is guaranteed to be compatible with the corresponding `urldecode()`.

If you want to learn how to do it "by yourself", read the source-code in the corresponding libraries to make sure you do not miss any scenario... it is generally a bad idea to re-implement library functions.

Comment: read the question well very before answering... you don't understand my question at all... second I posted `javascript` code not `php`...

Comment: Write the question very well before asking, and read my answer carefully. There is no need to do what you are doing in your question, if your purpose is to send a GET request. A call to `encodeURIComponent()` (which is standard JS, not PHP) is enough to encode each component. On the server side, you do not require any PHP at all to decode it (you write /encode the string for my link as similar to PHP/ in your question).